# Reading a checkbox value and writing to the http session in jsp

Tags: jsp, struts

My requirement is that is I want to dynamically read the checkbox value in the jsp and set it to the http session any idea how I can achive that ?

I am using struts 2 framework.

Comment: I don't know what you mean by "dynamically". If you want to update server-side state you need to make either an XHR or WebSocket call, noting that if you rely on the session value on the client side you'd need to update that via JS.

Answer (score 0):

You can pass params to your `.jsp` file through annotations.

```
 @Result(name = "success", type = "redirectAction",params = {"name", "${var}"}
```